# Building interactive version of dplyr functionality in Shiny

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I am building a Shiny app which processes multiple text files selected by a user. 
The output is a huge data frame with millions of rows and tens of columns. 
I am interested now to allow a user to interactively filter rows, select columns and summarize columns (by choosing from a list of functions such as mean, sd, max, min, sum, etc...). The result would be a smaller data frame summarizing the data per user selections - basically I need to create a GUI which implements a basic functionality of the dplyr library.

In general, I know how to do it by manually creating a bunch of GUI elements and feeding them into a server function with a number of dplyr commands. Since this seems to be a pretty standard functionality (GUI that filters and summarizes a dataframe), before I start building it from scratch, I am wondering if there is anything  "off the shelf" I can use either AS IS or as my starting point.

Comment: rpivotTable is pretty close to what you want. Except for the export. If they want to export, you'd probably have to dig into the callbacks to get the current state of the table.

Comment: I edited my question. I don't really need graphics and export capabilities to be part of the solution. I can easily implement them myself per specific requirements I have. In this regard rpivotTable is not what I need since it tries to do graphics but in not very elegant way and I don't see any customization options. Also, it does not return the summarized dataframe, so I cannot do any further processing with the result (such as export the data or create my own graphics).

Comment: There are actually a fair number of customization options, though you'll need to check out pivottable.js for the documentation (Much like with the other JS library ports to R, like DT, the documentation is mostly left for the JS lib to update, the html widget is just a wrapper). I found a way to return your output as a shiny object also, you just need to use the onRefresh param on rpivotTable, and then access it via the DOM.

Comment: this https://github.com/Yannael/queryBuildR or https://github.com/harveyl888/queryBuilder might also be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I know you said that `rpivotTable` wasn't quite what you're after, but I think it can be configured to do some of the heavy lifting,

Here's an example (using `rpivotTable` for the manipulation, `DT` to show the data.frame, `rvest` to parse the innerHTML from the DOM, there might be a better data format to pass the table object from the client side, but this is proof of concept):

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(rpivotTable)

FullPage <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('aSummaryTable'),
    rpivotTableOutput('RESULTS')
)

FullPage
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)
library(DT)
library(rvest)

function(input, output, session) {

  # Make some sample data
  qbdata <- reactive({
    expand.grid(LETTERS,1:3)
  })

  # Clean the html and store as reactive
  summarydf <- eventReactive(input$myData,{
    input$myData %>% 
       read_html %>% 
       html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% 
       # Turns out there are two tables in an rpivotTable, we want the second
       .[[2]]

  })

  # show df as DT::datatable
  output$aSummaryTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(summarydf(), rownames = FALSE)
  })

  # Whenever the config is refreshed, call back with the content of the table
  output$RESULTS <- renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(
      qbdata(),
      onRefresh = 
        htmlwidgets::JS("function(config) { 
                           Shiny.onInputChange('myData', document.getElementById('RESULTS').innerHTML); 
                        }")
    )
  })

}
```